# Insert blank pages into PDF when printing

Tags: pdf

I'm sure this problem is ubiquitous even though I can't seem to find answers. I would like my PDF document to display in the PDF reader with no blank pages, but then print with a blank page after the cover so the printed document comes out with odd pages on the right and even on the left. Has anyone else run into this problem and/or found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can use ****Multivalent tools****

download **Multivalent.jar** from one of these links *(latest free version with tools included)*

- https://rg.to/file/c6bd7f31bf8885bcaa69b50ffab7e355/Multivalent20060102.jar.html

put where you want and take in mind full path (e.g. where **Multivalent.jar** resides on system)

go to folder where you have pdf file

type in terminal

```
java -cp path...to/Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Split  -page 1,b,2-end input.pdf
```

and you will have a new pdf with one blank page before all others

if you have downloaded Multivalent.jar, let say, in **/mnt/home** , *Multivalent.jar* path will be

```
java -cp /mnt/home/Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Split  -page 1,b,2-end input.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, Dingo. If I understand right, this would add blank pages into my PDF, but the blank pages would still display in the reader, correct? I have no problem adding blank pages (with PDF Sam and others), but my problem lies in wanting to display the PDF differently than it is printed.

Comment: Multivalent is a much more advanced tool than PDFsam. To add a blank page with PDFsam, you first need to create this page in a word processor, save in pdf format and then join to other pages of your pdf

Comment: Multivalent is a much more advanced tool than PDFsam. To add a blank page with PDFsam, you first need to create this page in a word processor, save in pdf format and then join to other pages of your pdf. with Multivalent you can directly add blank pages, in one step. I understand your request; and maybe with javascript you can hide certain pages, but I don't know if non-shown pages will be printed, since I'm not expert in javascript coding