# PDF cover page printed as the only on the sheet, without empty pages inserted

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, inkscape, pdftk

I have a *make*-based workflow which uses *pdftk* to merge cover with LaTeX document.  The cover is generated by the following recipe (if that matters):

```
$(COVER) : $(patsubst %.pdf,%.svg,$(COVER))
    inkscape $< --export-area-page --batch-process --export-type=pdf --export-filename=$@ || inkscape --file=$< --export-area-page --export-area-drawing --without-gui --export-pdf=$@
```

When I view the document or print it single-sided, everything looks well.  But when I print it in double-sided, the first page of the document is obviously printed at the opposite side of the cover.  An obvious solution is to add a blank page - but that ruins document viewing and single-side printing.

How can I suggest (not necessarily force) printer to print the cover page single-sided by default?  Preferably without losing hyperlinks in both cover and the document.  Something to mark a page as "*the only in the sheet*" or "*the first in the sheet*" when printed.

I can use any tool available in Ubuntu, preferably commandline (so I can use it in the Makefile) or a Python package (so I can write an appropriate commandline tool myself).

An answer to [Insert blank pages into PDF when printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659585/insert-blank-pages-into-pdf-when-printing) does not help, as it does not cover hiding the blank pages when viewing/single side printing.

Comment: @KJ The problem is that when I deliver the final document, I have no control how it is printed as well as whether it is edited.  Is there anything in the PDF standard which allows to make a page the only one in the sheet?  Or the first one in the sheet?

Comment: @KJ I have no idea, but given that there is an option to "open in the presentation mode by default" I hope someone thought "that may be an useful option".  I had a similar idea as a fallback option (a legally required content).